# Dynamics CRM mobile client, how to add shortcut on an entity in left navigation pane

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-365, dynamics365-app-mobile

I am using dynamics 365 mobile app for IOS. I need to add the Email and Phone call entities shortcut into the main left navigation pane. Right now, I do not have any idea on how to add this.

Does anybody help me to add these shortcuts?

Answer (score 0):

You have to edit the sitemap to customize navigation.

You can use [Sitemap editor](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/workandstudybook/archive/2017/01/17/editing-sitemap-in-dynamics-365) to edit the [sitemap](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309424.aspx).

1. Open the Solution that you would like to use to contain the sitemap.
2. Under Components. Select Client Extensions > Add Existing > Select “Site Map”
3. Once it’s added to the solution, click on the Edit
4. It will then open up the Dynamics 365 Sitemap Editor.
5. Make changes, click Save and then Publish.

> Dynamics 365 for phones and tablets uses the same sitemap data to provide navigation options as the web application except that it is optimized for presentation in the mobile apps.

[Technet reference](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn531159.aspx#Change%20navigation%20options%20for%20Dynamics%20365%20for%20phones%20and%20tablets)

Comment: Thanks for the response, it seems like if we change the Sitemap then it will also change the navigation of the web but here we do not want to change the navigation of the Web but we only need to change the navigation of mobile app only.